Inconsistent result using matrix for non-standard basis
I am making what I suspect is a very basic error and would like to know where I"m going wrong. In short, I am developing a matrix for a linear mapping using a non-standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Yet when I multiply the basis vectors by the developed matrix, I get a different answer than the specified mapping.
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear mapping defined by $T(\textbf{x})=(ax_1+bx_2, cx_1+dx_2)$. Determine the matrix $A=M(T)$ for the $\mathbb{R}^2$ ordered basis $(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \end{bmatrix})$.
First, I determine the mappings for each basis vector:
$$T(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}a+b \\c+d \end{bmatrix} \\
T(\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}b-a \\d-c \end{bmatrix} \\
$$
Then I find the coefficeints so that each of the above is expressed as a linear combination of the ordered basis, i.e.
$$\begin{bmatrix}a+b \\c+d \end{bmatrix}=u\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}+v\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}b-a \\d-c \end{bmatrix}=w\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
After solving for $u,v,w,z$, I record them in a matrix like so:
$$M(T)=\begin{bmatrix}u&w \\ v&z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}&\frac{b-a+d-c}{2} \\ \frac{c+d-a-b}{2}&\frac{d-c-b+a}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
To check the answer, I then multiply $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ by the above matrix expecting to get $T(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}a+b \\c+d \end{bmatrix}$ but instead get $\begin{bmatrix}b+d \\d-b \end{bmatrix}$. Surely this cannot be correct, so where am I going wrong?
Edit: My mistake as pointed out by others was assuming a column vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is equivalent to a vector $(1,1)$. Column vectors are actually the coefficients of the linear combination of the basis vectors, so I was implicitly adding the standard basis in by neglecting this fact.

The product $M(T)\begin{bmatrix}1\1\end{bmatrix}$ is the result of interpreting $\begin{bmatrix}1\1\end{bmatrix}$ as a coordinate vector with respect to your non-standard basis, then applying $T$, then converting the result back to a coordinate vector. So, you are really mapping $$1\begin{bmatrix}1\1\end{bmatrix}+1\begin{bmatrix}-1\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\2\end{bmatrix}$$and the result is$$(b+d)\begin{bmatrix}1\1\end{bmatrix}+(d-b)\begin{bmatrix}-1\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2b\2d\end{bmatrix},$$which is $T\begin{bmatrix}0\2\end{bmatrix}$. It checks out.

Welcome to mathematics stack exchange.  Remember that your matrix corresponds to the linear transformation in your non-standard basis coordinates

@TheoBendit so it seems I"ve conflated the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\1\end{bmatrix}$ in the matrix product with the one that is part of the non-standard basis? I guess it's a notation issue like Andreas mentioned.

in this kind of problem the notation is what saves you (an more generally everywhere). I will now remark the steps to show you what the representations without additional notation is hiding from you.

Let us first the space: you didn't explicitate a basis $B$ for $\mathbb R^2$ when you defined the operator $T$ (or even if you did implicitly, let's pretend you didn't and continue), so call $B=E_2$, hence the standart basis for $\mathbb R^2$. Call $B'= \left(\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}_{E_2},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}_{E_2}\right)$, notice that I added an extra index to denote the current basis of representation to which the coordinate vector relates.
Consider now the linear operator you mentioned:
\begin{align*}
T:\mathbb R^2&\rightarrow\mathbb R^2\\
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}_{E_2} &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}ax_1 + bx_2\\ cx_1 + dx_2\end{pmatrix}_{E_2}
\end{align*}
I took the freedom to deliberately choose the representation basis for this map, as we assumed none where provided. In this basis the representation matrix for $T$ is the following:
$$_{E_2}[T]_{E_2} = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
This notation is very useful whenever you have to deal with general tenor-like objects (scalars, vectors, matrices, etc), in this case because its immediately clarifies what is the basis of the starting space (bottom-right) and landing space (bottom-left)
A result frome linear algebra shows you that the change of basis transformation for a linear map takes the following shape:
$$_{B'}[T]_{B'}= _{B'}[id]_{B}\cdot _{B}[T]_{B} \cdot _{B}[id]_{B'}$$
Here $B= E_2$ and hence we already have the central matrix.
We are now only missing the change of basis representation, you can see that the underlying map is the identity, since the purpose is to maintain the same object, but adapt its representation to a different basis. A smart way to do so, here, is to look at the representation
$$_{E_2}[id]_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix}|&|\\ \left[b_1\right]_{E_2}&\left[b_2\right]_{E_2}\\ |&|\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
and then invert it to also get the inverse change of basis direction, so
$$_{B'}[id]_{E_2}= _{E_2}[id]_{B'}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
We can now compute the above matrix repesentation of $T$ as
$$_{B'}[T]_{B'}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}&\frac{-a-c+b+d}{2}\\ \frac{-a+c-b+d}{2}&\frac{a-c-b+d}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
Say that now you want to check your result and so you let $b_1$ pass through the map; remember that $b_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}_{E_2}$. Now the map representation here above ($_{B'}[T]_{B'}$) already tells you which elements go in and in which representations, namely those in base $B'$, so calculationg $_{B'}[T]_{B'}\cdot[b_1]_{B'} =_{B'}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}&\frac{-a-c+b+d}{2}\\ \frac{-a+c-b+d}{2}&\frac{a-c-b+d}{2}\end{pmatrix}_{B'} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\\ \frac{c+d-a-b}{2}\end{pmatrix}_{B'}$ which is equal to $_{E_2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}_{B'}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\\ \frac{c+d-a-b}{2}\end{pmatrix}_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix}a+b\\ c+d\end{pmatrix}_{E_2}$
Last but not least, suppose now that everything until now is correct but it kind of answer another question and originally you already intended to have the $B'$ basis as default, do we have to redo everything again from the beginning? No, we already have the change of basis representations and the map representations, so by simply switching the indices for the basis we get the same result but starting now already with the current $B'$ basis . Attention here: this new way of portraing the map gives birth to a totally different map the the one we got so far, since by changing the basis we get two different results in the same basis.

Finally, my suggestion is to always pay attention to the respect to which basis you are working with: "notation saves your life".
P.S. In some cases the lower indices are at the wrong height, I'm sorry about that, but can't do much about it now.

I thought by specifying the non-standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ I was paying attention to the basis, but I guess I was implicitly using the standard basis when doing so. Thanks for the answer!

@OftenConfused you are welcome. I wish it helped.
